# 'py' works but not 'python' in command prompt for windows 10

Tags: python, environment-variables

I installed Python on my computer.

When I type `python` in the command prompt I get the following message:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But when I type `py` it seems to be working and I get the following:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64
bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license"
for more information.
```

Why is this happening?

FYI: I checked the path variable in environmental variables and I don't see any path to python installation.

But then how is visual code able to find the path to `python.exe` and able to run python code?

I am confused.

Comment: just add the path to the python exe

Comment: Take a look at that: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/dirs/Windows/py_exe#:~:text=C%3A%5CWindows%5Cpy.exe%20is,the%20Python%20Launcher%20for%20Windows.&text=py.exe%20helps%20to%20execute,to%20a%20specific%20Python%20executable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`py` is itself located in `C:\Windows` (which is always part of the `PATH`), which is why you find it. When you installed Python, you didn't check the box to add it to your `PATH`, which is why it isn't there. In general, it's best to use the [Windows Python Launcher, `py.exe`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) anyway, so this is no big deal. Just use `py` for launching consistently, and stuff will just work. Similarly, if `py.exe` was associated with the `.py` extension at installation time, a standard shebang line (details in PEP linked above) will let you run the script without even typing `py`.

I don't know precisely what VSCode uses to find Python (using `py.exe` directly, using a copy of Python that ships with the editor, performing registry lookup, a config file that just says where to find it, etc.), but that's not really relevant to running your scripts yourself.

Comment: Also, I have one more question related to environmental variables.  
How does Windows know when i type in 'py' to choose which of the many path variables to choose(it has path to .net,java,sql etc). Does it go through all the paths one by one?

Comment: @SuperAadi: `py` isn't a Windows thing, it's installed with sufficiently modern Python installations. The PEP I linked contains the details on how it looks things up (it's not via the `PATH`), and it's only looking up Python (so .net, java, and sql aren't involved). You provide it command line switches to choose which version to use; when those switches are omitted, it just runs the most modern install.

Comment: @SuperAadi: It searches them, one by one from left to right in the `PATH`, until it finds something that matches. If you provide the full name, `py.exe`, it looks for that specifically, if you just type `py`, it uses the `PATHEXT` variable to check for anything that is named `py` plus one of the extensions in `PATHEXT` (e.g. `.exe`, `.com`, `.bat`, etc.). It's always using the first one found (`py.exe` exists because this "first found" behavior made it hard to use multiple versions of Python; only one could be first in the `PATH`, but they're all named `python.exe`, so choosing was a problem).

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to system properties -> Advance
2. Click environment variables
3. Edit the 'PATH' variable
4. Add 2 new paths 'C:\Python37' and 'C:\Python37\scripts'
5. Run cmd again and type python.

It should work!

Or you can use the graphical way of Python Installer.
Run the python installer and select Modify option
[image]

Press next on next window if you need nothing changed.

Then next window Select **Add Python to environment variables**
Continue the installation.
[image]

Make sure you get a new terminal to test whether it works

Comment: I have python 3.9 added to path and it doesn't work

Comment: @SmoothNeon Check now I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could try execute in cmd:

```
where py
```

Output will be paths to the executable. E.g:

```
C:\Users\user>where python
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

This helps you track down, which one is executed.

Comment: `where` can't find `python` if it's not in the `PATH`.