# Can't pip install numpy

Tags: python, windows, pip, mingw

I've managed to make `pip install robotframework`, but it's not allowing me to `pip install numpy` (and `opcua`). Furthermore, if I run again `pip install robot framework` it tells me that:

```
Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (6.0.2)
```

The command `python --version` returns 3.10.9.

Additional info: Python does not appear in the install/uninstall application list on control panel.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYnG3.png) is what's on the PATH variable.

Below is the exact output from the cmd:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
Using cached numpy-1.24.3.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [40 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
main()
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
backend = _build_backend()
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
obj = import_module(mod_path)
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\afonso.teixeira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51uqq44g\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
monkey.patch_all()
File "C:\Users\afonso.teixeira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51uqq44g\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
File "C:\Users\afonso.teixeira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51uqq44g\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
File "C:\Users\afonso.teixeira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51uqq44g\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\afonso.teixeira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-51uqq44g\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Please provide the actual output of `pip install numpy` by copying it (or even taking a screenshot) and pasting it here. If the output is too big you can leave out the beginning and just provide the last several lines (the more the better)

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you do `pip install numpy`? Please edit your question and provide the message as text (not a screenshot!).

Comment: @DrEichenbach I did provided it. But placed it inside three `, and it was messed up. Just pasted normally as text, and it's a bit weird with lack of spaces

Comment: @Matthias I just did. It's weird. If you got any idea on how to improve read-ability for you guys, just hit me up

Comment: Oh, oh. mingw and numpy. You could try to install it as described at https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-numpy.

Comment: @Matthias explain me like I'm 5: why can I install robotframework with pip on cmd, and I have to install numpy with pacman on mingw terminal? Is that even installing both things on the same python? I have no idea what I'm doing with these commands and installations, but I apparently need these packages alongside python to work with robot framework

Comment: @ATSlooking4things I can't answer your question, otherwise I would have. I only remember reading about problems with this constellation.

Comment: @Matthias didn't meant to be rude. Was more of a self-deprecating comment, because I truly am clueless. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`python` was MSYS MINGW64's python.

`py` was my installation of python.

To install what I wanted in the correct version, I just had to use `py -m pip install` instead

Comment: what do you mean by `py` here?

Comment: @SwaminathBera AFAIK it's just a normal installation of python, but that you reference through cmd by calling `py` instead of `python`. I had different versions of python installed, and each had their "reference". More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941146/21186572 and in his comments below.